# Why there's a break between each .hgt srtm tile when importing to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, tiles, srtm, hgt

When I import the .hgt srtm elevation data to QGIS, the each tiles(each .hgt files) stitches with with a break or contrast variance or something like this:

[image]

And it gets worst when rendering it with Qgis2threejs:

[image]

I tried it viewing with 3DEM, the data seems to be perfect in there.
Please help me with this thing.

Comment: If you wan them to be view them as a single block you have either to build a virtual raster or merge them. The same goes for the variation in contrast

Comment: Build a virtual raster - http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/177837/2856

Answer (score 1):

Apart from stitching the DEMs into a single file, you can apply the same styling to the SRTM files.

QGIS uses the 2% and 98% values of each tile for min and max (black and white) colour (or greyscale) interpolating, so each has a different colour ramp.

Applying the same style to **all** tiles will give you a contiguos look. You might have to expand min and max to cover all values.